# somatoChart in r (plot or ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to make a replica of the somatoChart to characterize the somatotype of some athletes, I need some adjustments to get the result I expect, figure left my code, figure right what I hope.

[image]

```
x <- c(0,-6,6,0,-4.5,4.5,0)
y <- c(12,-6,-6,0,4.5,4.5,-7.5)
par(mar = c(2,0,0,2), mgp = c(2,1,0))
plot(x,y,pch = 20,xlab = " ",ylab = " ",xlim = c(-8,8), ylim = c(-10,16),las = 1, col = "white",axes = F)
axis(4, las = 1, yaxp = c(-10,16,13),cex.axis=0.8)
axis(1, xaxp = c(-8, 8, 16),cex.axis=0.8)
# Segmentes
segments(x0 = 0, y0=-7.5, x1 = 0, y1 = 12, lty = 2)
segments(x0 = -6, y0=-6, x1 = 4.5, y1 = 4.5, lty = 2)
segments(x0 = 6, y0=-6, x1 = -4.5, y1 = 4.5, lty = 2)
# text
windowsFonts(B=windowsFont("Bookman Old Style"))
text(0,13,"MESOMORPH", cex = 0.6,family="B", font = 2)
text(-6,-8,"ENDOMORPH",cex = 0.6,family="B", font = 2)
text(6,-8,"ECTOMORPH", cex = 0.6,family="B", font = 2)
# curves
segments(x0 = -4.5, y0=4.5, x1 = 0, y1 = 12)
segments(x0 = -4.5, y0=4.5, x1 = -6, y1 = -6)
segments(x0 = 0, y0=-7.5, x1 = -6, y1 = -6)
segments(x0 = 0, y0=-7.5, x1 = 6, y1 = -6)
segments(x0 = 4.5, y0=4.5, x1 = 6, y1 = -6)
segments(x0 = 4.5, y0=4.5, x1 = 0, y1 = 12)
```

Would readers make suggestions please?

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve? Add points? Or is there something else?

Comment: I need to get the soft edges, the points do not matter since they can vary according to the data of the athletes.

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I'm from Latin America and therefore I do not speak English very well, so some things from my language and culture may look different in English, but I'll take into account your comment, if you do not feel like someone is excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps using `xspline` can solve your problem:

```
x <- c(0,-6,6,0,-4.5,4.5,0)
y <- c(12,-6,-6,0,4.5,4.5,-7.5)
par(mar = c(2,0,0,2), mgp = c(2,1,0))
plot(x,y,pch = 20,xlab = " ",ylab = " ",xlim = c(-8,8), ylim = c(-10,16),las = 1, col = "white",axes = F)
axis(4, las = 1, yaxp = c(-10,16,13),cex.axis=0.8)
axis(1, xaxp = c(-8, 8, 16),cex.axis=0.8)
# Segmentes
segments(x0 = 0, y0=-7.5, x1 = 0, y1 = 12, lty = 2)
segments(x0 = -6, y0=-6, x1 = 4.5, y1 = 4.5, lty = 2)
segments(x0 = 6, y0=-6, x1 = -4.5, y1 = 4.5, lty = 2)
# text
windowsFonts(B=windowsFont("Bookman Old Style"))
text(0,13,"MESOMORPH", cex = 0.6,family="B", font = 2)
text(-6,-8,"ENDOMORPH",cex = 0.6,family="B", font = 2)
text(6,-8,"ECTOMORPH", cex = 0.6,family="B", font = 2)

xspline(y = c(-6, 4.5, 12), x =  c(-6, -4.5, 0), shape = -1, lty = 2)
xspline(y = c(-6, -7.5,-6), x =  c(-6, 0, 6), shape = -1, lty = 2)
xspline(y = c(-6, 4.5, 12), x = c(6, 4.5, 0),  shape = -1, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone came here looking for how to make a somatochart chart, here I share the one I did with Highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/aledc/1m89wju0/2/

and the code:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="somatocarta" style="height:450px;width:500px;"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var data = [
         {"x":0,"y":0},      // en el Centro
         {"x":-10,"y":30},   // cuadrante Superioro Alto Izquierdo
         {"x":15,"y":35},    // cuadrante Superior Alto Derecho
         {"x":45,"y":13},    // cuadrante Superior Medio Derecho
         {"x":52,"y":-13},   // cuadrante Inferior Medio Derecho
         {"x":25,"y":-33},   // cuadrante Inferior Bajo Derecho
         {"x":-25,"y":-33},  // cuadrante Inferior Bajo Izquierdo
         {"x":-42,"y":-14},  // cuadrante Inferior Medio Izquierdo   
         {"x":-42,"y":14},   // cuadrante Superior Medio Izquierdo

    ]

    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));


    Highcharts.chart('somatocarta', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundImage: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aledc7/Laravel/master/resources/somatocarta.png',
        renderTo: 'somatocarta',
            defaultSeriesType:'scatter',
            borderWidth:1,
            borderColor:'#ccc',
            marginLeft:90,
            marginRight:50,
    },

    title:{
            text:'Somatocarta'
        },
        legend:{
            enabled:false                                
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                shadow:false,
            }
        },
        xAxis:{
            title:{
                text:'X Axis Title'
            },
            min:-100,
            max:100,
            tickInterval:100,
            tickLength:0,
            minorTickLength:0,
            gridLineWidth:1,
            showLastLabel:true,
            showFirstLabel:false,
            lineColor:'#ccc',
            lineWidth:1                
        },
        yAxis:{
            title:{
                text:'Y Axis<br/>Title',
                rotation:0,
                margin:25,
            },
            min:-100,
            max:100,
            tickInterval:100,
            tickLength:3,
            minorTickLength:0,
            lineColor:'#ccc',
            lineWidth:1        
        },
        series: [{
            color:'#185aa9',
            data: data
        }]
});
```